# C++ struct sorting error

Tags: c++, struct, sorting, functor

I am trying to sort a vector of custom struct in C++

```
struct Book{
public:int H,W,V,i;
};
```

with a simple functor

```
class CompareHeight
{
public:
    int operator() (Book lhs,Book rhs)
    {
        return lhs.H-rhs.H; 
    }
};
```

when trying :

```
vector<Book> books(X);
.....
sort(books.begin(),books.end(), CompareHeight());
```

it gives me exception  "invalid operator <"

What is the meaning of this error?

Thanks

Comment: BTW what is your toolchain (compiler/library)? I'm curious which does recognize this kind of error.

Comment: I use VS 2008.. 
I think recognizing this exception means it does more work in runtime, therefore it is less efficient w.r.t running time.. Am I right?

Comment: @jpalecek: Dinkumware has some sanity checks for stuff like this in their library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sort` expects a function that returns `bool`, which is true iff the lhs precedes the rhs:

```
bool operator() (const Book& lhs, const Book& rhs)
{
    return lhs.H < rhs.H; 
}
```

Also note the change to `const Book&` parameters, to avoid copying.